# Android Architecture Components ViewModel context issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components

I am trying to use the new Architecture Components in Android, and so far it has worked pretty well. However, I have stumbled into an architectural problem.

I have a `MainActivity` that hosts a bunch of fragments, `A`, `B`, and `C`. Until now, every time I need my ViewModel (VM) I fetch it in the context of `MainActivity` (like this: `MyViewModel vm = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);`). Now consider this:

- Fragment `C` lets the user select some value, and writes it to the `VM`.
- Fragment `A` uses fragment `C` to have the user select the value, and then `A` reads the value directly from `VM` and shows it in its UI.
- Fragment `B` uses the same approach as fragment `A`.

The problem is, that since the `VM` is always in the context of the `MainActivity`, if fragment `A` has been used before `B`, the value will still be available, and `B` will show some old data.

The most obvious solution that I see is to create the `VM` in the contexts of fragments `A` and `B` respectively. But then I cannot figure out how to let fragment `C` access those `VM`s.

I could also create the `VM` in the context of fragment `C`, but that would require fragments `A` and `B` to create an instance of `C`, which I don't think is a nice solution.

A third solution would be keep the current approach and clear the data in the `VM` when appropriate, but that's also messy, I think.

What is the nicest way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a mapping in VM and store the values for `A` and `B` under different keys.

So, when `A` starts `C` it passes its `A_key` as an argument. When user chooses a value in `C`, it is being stored in VM's map using `A_key` as a key. When `A` checks whether a value is available, it only checks the value stored for `A_key`.

The same for `B` and `B_key`.